# change part of the text color in UiBinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I have a text:

```
<g:Label ui:field="titleLabel">text RedText someMoreText</g:Label>
```

Now I'd like to make `RedText` red. I can't set any widget inside `<g:Label>` tags, or html elements. But how is this done then?

Comment: you'd have to make a custom widget, or a method, to easily wrap your red text inside a `<span>` tag with red font coloring.

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you can use `<g:InlineLable>` inside your `<g:Lable>` and then style the `InlineLable` with color Red. Or you can use `<span>` element with an id/class as per requirement and style it accordingly to red color.